# App for android to receive data and save on smartphone from server BLE5

Tags: android, bluetooth

with the next code, I can receive data with length 10 bytes in Windows from server device via ble5

```
FIRST_NAME_ID =12d6-5757-gjh6-fgyu-34gh
address = 45:g5:45:33:31:90

async def main(address):
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        def callback(FIRST_NAME_ID, data):
            print ("len data", len(data))  // len data = 10 bytes                  
        await client.start_notify(FIRST_NAME_ID, callback)  
        while 1: 
          if not event.is_set():    
              await event.wait()  
          event.clear()
event = asyncio.Event()
print('address:', address)
asyncio.run(main(address))
```

but I need to receive data on smartphone, android and save it
I already installed about 30 different apps from the store, but in the best way they can receive only 1 byte
But I need to receive and save data on my phone
Maybe some app can do it or exist some sdk

Comment: Sorry but Stackoverflow is a site for developers, therefore if you post here we would expect that you build your own app. You you look at GitHub and similar sites you will find several examples on how to receive data via Bluetooth on Android but be aware that the code is way more complex than your Bleak example.